# How to only send one specific file with rsync

Tags: python, rsync

I am writing a backup script in python and for part of it I need to zip all of the contents of a directory and then send that zipped file via rsync to a remote host. I have tried

```
os.system("rsync -avzhe --include='*.tar' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ssh " + 
          BACKUP_FROM_PATH + " root@" + IPADDRESS + ":" + TARGET_DIR)
```

I know that before I added the include and exclude statements that this line sent all of the contents in my BACK_FROM_PATH directory, including the zip file and all of the individual contents that made up the zip file. I only want to send the zip file however and not the individual contents that make up the file. When I added the include and exclude I get a message that says --include=*.tar: No such file or directory but there is in fact a file in my current directory with a .tar extension.

Comment: If you want to send only one file, which is a zip archive (so no meaningful deltas), why would you use `rsync` and not `scp`?

Comment: Well I don't know why. I originally tried scp before I was told I had to zip the file and my manager told me to use rsync. Now that I just have to send the zipped file I agreed that scp would work better, kinda drew a blank. thanks

Comment: Well ... rather `sftp` if the file is larger.

Comment: i am confused. do you want to transfer one zip file or a folder structure recursively? your text and your code with its arguments (`include */` and `exclude *`) paint a very confusing picture.